# Is there a way I can fix my header component to stop displaying blank due to react router version 6.4.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**I learnt React router version 5 but I do not understand how version 6.4.3 works

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header/>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './Header.css';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import VideoCallIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VideoCall';
import AppsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Apps';
import NotificationAddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/NotificationAdd';
import { Avatar } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Header() {
  const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState('');
  return (
    
    <div className='header'>
      <div className='header_left'>
      <MenuIcon />
      <Link to='/'>
      <img 
      className='header_logo'
      src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg' 
      alt='' />
      </Link>
      </div>
      <div className='header_input'>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInputSearch(e.target.value)}
      value={inputSearch} 
      type='text' placeholder='Search'/>
     
      <Link to={`/search/${inputSearch}`}> 
      <SearchIcon className='header_inputbutton' />
```

type here

```
      </Link>
      </div> 
      <div className='header_icons'>
      <VideoCallIcon className='header_icon' />
      <AppsIcon className='header_icon'/>
      <NotificationAddIcon className='header_icon'/>
      <Avatar src='' alt='Igbe Ajaga'/>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

I tried to use react router but the Header component which has react router imported is displaying a blank white space on my browser while the other components without react router are displaying correctly.**

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Can you edit the post to include a complete [mcve] so we can see how this `Header` component relates to any `react-router-dom` code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! 
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
Link from react-router-dom that is used in my codes is making my Header.js component display empty/blank on the browser

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear what you are referring to. Can you edit the post to include a [mcve] so we can see complete code and attempt to reproduce ourselves if necessary?